# JMeter syntax for passing some cookies between threads

Tags: jmeter

I want one thread to log onto our system 10 times, then in the next thread to call a webpage 10 times, once per logged on user. This means each user will need a set of unique cookies (authentication, session, etc)

The first page will return cookies, one set per logon, that need to be passed to the second set of webpages

The code below doesn't work. This code is in a JSR223 Preprocessor

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.CollectionProperty;
     
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getCookieManager();

CollectionProperty cookies = manager.getCookies();

def NbOfCookies = manager.getCookieCount();

for (def i = 0; i < NbOfCookies; i++) 
{
    string name = "cookie." + manager.get(i).getName()+ ${__threadNum};
    ${__setProperty(name, manager.get(i).getValue(),)}
}
```

The output I see via DebugSampler is

```
"cookie." + manager.get(i).getName() + 1= manager.get(i).getValue()
```

Clearly not what I want

It seems the CookieManager has a getter to get all cookies, and a setter to set cookies individually., i.e. they don't match up, so I'm not sure what the code on the other side will look like

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("<just one cookie?>",props.get("<just one cookie?>"),"<our website>","/",false,0);
manager.add(cookie);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts, the reasons are in:

1. The syntax conflicts with Groovy's [GStrings](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_gstring_and_string_hashcodes)
2. Functions or variables may evaluate into something causing compilation failure or unexpected behaviour
3. [JSR223 Test Elements cache compiled scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) so only first occurrence will be used for subsequent calls

Suggested code change:

```
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getCookieManager();

def NbOfCookies = manager.getCookieCount();

for (def i = 0; i < NbOfCookies; i++) {
    def name = "cookie." + manager.get(i).getName() + ctx.getThreadNum()
    props.put(name, manager.get(i).getValue(),)
}
```

And demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

---

P.S. wouldn't be easier to use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)? The [example test plan](https://jmeter-plugins.org/editor/?utm_source=jpgc&utm_medium=openurl&utm_campaign=examples#/img/examples/SynchronizationExample.jmx) shows passing a cookie between threads.

Comment: This looks ideal, thanks for that. I'll be back on this tomorrow so can hopefully sort it then